# Debian shell script to update server software

Tags: linux, debian, shell, apt

A lot of my server software is installed via apt-get and I was wondering if there is a small shell script I can get which will will update all of this software. Also do I need to restart my server afterwards or stop the scripts from running before I run this update?

Is it really as simple as:

```
apt-get update?
```

Comment: You could run "apt-get -s upgrade" to simulate only, then grep this output for packages like "linux-image" or the like and then only reboot if such a kernel package is to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `apt-get update` downloads the package lists from the repositories and "updates" them to get information on the newest versions of packages. You then also need to execute `apt-get upgrade` to actually install updates.

Answer (score 0):

No, restarting the whole sytem would only be necessary if you had upgraded the kernel itself. This would require a reboot in most cases. Everything else, including the stopping and restarting of services, should be handled by the package system.

BTW: You should take a look at **cron-apt** - this tool downloads upgraded packages at night, which then can be installed manuall with **apt-get update**.